# How to differential spline graph in the matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm the begginer of the matlab. So i can't find how to differential the spline graph. So could you explain me how to differential spline graph?

I wanna differential the graph below

```
x = -4:4;
y = [0 .15 1.12 2.36 2.36 1.46 .49 .06 0];
cs = spline(x,[0 y 0]);
xx = linspace(-4,4,101);
plot(ppval(cs,xx));
```

Comment: I have to submit my project until tomorrrow.... Could you help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.